# How AngularJS filter and ng-model work in context of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to understand AngularJS ng-model directive and I found [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)
I'm not able to understand how filters are working internally. 
Actually its

```
Any: <input ng-model="search.$"> <br>
Name only <input ng-model="search.name"><br>
Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"><br>

<tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

When I remove first input box Any, and then convert second input box's model from search.name to search. Then its not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's take a look.
You told: "When I remove first input box Any, and then convert second input box's model from search.name to search".

Do, we can see the following HTML:

```
Name only <input ng-model="search"><br>
Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"><br>

<tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now when you type anything in **Name** input - your table is filtered by all fields. In our case these fields are `friendObj.name` and `friendObj.phone`. It happens because you use *string* expression of search (take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), when `expression` is a *String*). In this moment your `search` variable is a string and you do not see any changes in the **Phone** input field because it's binded to the `search.phone` variable, but the last does not exist because `search` is not an object, and it does not contain `phone` field.

Now you try to type anything in the **Phone** field. In this moment your `search` variable becomes an object, something like that:

```
 search = {phone: 'YourText'}
```

Your table now is filtered by only `friendObj.phone` field. It happens because you use *Object* expression of search ([the same link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), when `expression` is an *Object*).
Now you can see in the field **Name** text `[object Object]`. It happens because the **Name** field is binded to the `search` variable. But in this moment, as i told you, it's an *Object* and AngularJS tries to make a string from this object. As far as you know (i hope ;) ), when you try to modify `Object` to the primitive `String` - is called ***toString()*** function of object which returns `[object Object]` string.

Hope i anwered your question.